# JOLT - Adding fields in JSONArray based on if condition

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, transform, jolt

I have a bit of a tricky question to ask, as far as I know, I haven't seen anyone with the same problem, at least not all of them at once!

I have the following test JSON to transform:

**INPUT**

```
[
  {
    "test_id": 1212101011,
    "someDate": "2020-03-06",
    "keyToCheck": "true",
    "someData": "123"
  },
  {
    "test_id": 8787909099,
    "someDate": "2020-03-09",
    "keyToCheck": "false",
    "someData": "456"
  }
]
```

And I am trying to get the following output.

**DESIRED**

```
[{
   "test_id": 1212101011,
   "someDate": "2020-03-06",
   "keyToCheck": "true",
   "someData": "123",
   "objToAdd": {
      "id": "1",
      "label": "dummy1"
   }
},{
   "test_id": 8787909099,
   "someDate": "2020-03-09",
   "keyToCheck": "false",
   "someData": "456",
   "objToAdd": {
      "id": "2",
      "label": "dummy2"
}]
```

I already managed to propagate all the values and change the fields' names if needed, but adding a condition is just ruining everything. Also, with the current spec I have, I am not getting an array after the transform which I can already get with my former spec.

The spec I have so far is:

**SPEC USED**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "keyToCheck": {
          "true": {
            "#1": "objToAdd.id",
            "#dummy1": "objToAdd.label"
          },
          "false": {
            "#2": "objToAdd.id",
            "#dummy2": "objToAdd.label"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But as said before, it is only giving me this:

**RESULT SO FAR**

```
{
  "objToAdd" : {
    "id" : [ "1", "2" ],
    "label" : [ "dummy1", "dummy2" ]
  }
}
```

Which seems to be a problem of indentation. Adding [&1] before the values in the condition didn't help, and when I propagate the values with "*": "[&1].&", I am losing the item generated by the if-else condition.

Is there any way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "test_id": "[&1].test_id",
        "someDate": "[&1].someDate",
        "someData": "[&1].someData",
        "keyToCheck": {
          "true": {
            "$": "[&3].keyToCheck",
            "#1": "[&3].objToAdd.id",
            "#dummy1": "[&3].objToAdd.label"
          },
          "false": {
            "$": "[&3].keyToCheck",
            "#2": "[&3].objToAdd.id",
            "#dummy2": "[&3].objToAdd.label"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```